# vue.config.js shows different chunks and size in production build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, webpack-splitchunks

I've upgraded my application from **webpack** to **vue-cli@4.5.17**. But, I'm getting different size and different numbers of chunk in production build output.

**vue.config.js**

```js
    'use strict'
    const path = require('path')
    const defaultSettings = require('./src/settings.js')
    
    function resolve(dir) {
      return path.join(__dirname, dir)
    }
    
    const name = defaultSettings.title || 'Product Title' // page title
    
    const port = process.env.port || process.env.npm_config_port || 9527 // dev port
    
    
    module.exports = {
      runtimeCompiler: true,
      publicPath: '/',
      outputDir: 'dist',
      assetsDir: 'static',
      lintOnSave: false,
      productionSourceMap: false,
      devServer: {
        host: 'project.localhost',
        disableHostCheck: false,
        port: port,
        https: true,
        open: true,
        compress: true,
        overlay: {
          warnings: false,
          errors: true,
        },
      },
      css: { extract: true },
      configureWebpack: {
        name: name,
        resolve: {
          alias: {
            '@': resolve('src'),
          },
        },
      },
      chainWebpack(config) {
        config.plugin('html').tap((args) => {
          args[0].filename = 'index.html'
          args[0].template = 'index.html'
          args[0].favicon = resolve('favicon.ico')
          args[0].title = 'Product Title'
          args[0].templateParameters = {
            BASE_URL: '/static',
          }
          return args
        })
        config.plugin('preload').tap(() => [
          {
            rel: 'preload',
            // to ignore runtime.js
            // https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/app.js#L171
            fileBlacklist: [/\.map$/, /hot-update\.js$/, /runtime\..*\.js$/],
            include: 'initial',
          },
        ])
    
        // when there are many pages, it will cause too many meaningless requests
        config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
    
        // thumbnail url loader
        config.module
          .rule('images')
          .exclude.add(resolve('src/icons'))
          .end()
          .use('url-loader')
          .tap((options) => {
            options.limit = 10000
            return options
          })
        // set svg-sprite-loader
        config.module.rule('svg').exclude.add(resolve('src/icons')).end()
        config.module
          .rule('icons')
          .test(/\.svg$/)
          .include.add(resolve('src/icons'))
          .end()
          .use('svg-sprite-loader')
          .loader('svg-sprite-loader')
          .options({
            symbolId: 'icon-[name]',
          })
          .end()
    
        config.when(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development', (config) => {
          config
            .plugin('ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin')
            .after('html')
            .use('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin', [
              {
                // `runtime` must same as runtimeChunk name. default is `runtime`
                inline: /runtime\..*\.js$/,
              },
            ])
            .end()
          config.optimization.splitChunks({
            chunks: 'all',
            cacheGroups: {
              libs: {
                name: 'chunk-libs',
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                priority: 10,
                chunks: 'initial', // only package third parties that are initially dependent
              },
              elementUI: {
                name: 'chunk-elementUI', // split elementUI into a single package
                priority: 20, // the weight needs to be larger than libs and app or it will be packaged into libs or app
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]_?element-ui(.*)/, // in order to adapt to cnpm
              },
              commons: {
                name: 'chunk-commons',
                test: resolve('src/components'), // can customize your rules
                minChunks: 3, //  minimum common number
                priority: 5,
                reuseExistingChunk: true,
              },
            },
          })
          // https:// webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk
          config.optimization.runtimeChunk('single')
        })
      },
    }
```

And the Output is following:

**OUTPUT-1**

```
⠏  Building for dev...

 WARNING  Compiled with 3 warnings                                                                                                                                3:32:20 PM

 warning  

asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  static/img/fa-brands-400.1d5619cd.svg (730 KiB)
  static/img/fa-solid-900.37bc7099.svg (897 KiB)
  static/img/fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d.svg (434 KiB)
  static/js/app.57cf5156.js (857 KiB)
  static/js/chunk-elementUI.2bd32906.js (698 KiB)
  static/js/chunk-libs.b0b64aa5.js (4.87 MiB)

 warning  

entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  app (6.89 MiB)
      static/css/chunk-elementUI.68c70ad5.css
      static/js/chunk-elementUI.2bd32906.js
      static/css/chunk-libs.99e7fe66.css
      static/js/chunk-libs.b0b64aa5.js
      static/css/app.e4736649.css
      static/js/app.57cf5156.js


 warning  

webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

  File                                            Size                                                        Gzipped

  dist/static/js/chunk-libs.b0b64aa5.js           4987.71 KiB                                                 1731.28 KiB
  dist/static/js/app.57cf5156.js                  856.52 KiB                                                  254.17 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-elementUI.2bd32906.js      697.86 KiB                                                  170.93 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-elementUI.68c70ad5.css    227.82 KiB                                                  34.54 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-libs.99e7fe66.css         190.53 KiB                                                  38.37 KiB
  dist/static/css/app.e4736649.css                98.98 KiB                                                   19.17 KiB

  Images and other types of assets omitted.
```

**OUTPUT-2 (Expected)**

```
⠼  Building for dev...

 WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings                                                                                                                                2:53:57 PM

 warning  

asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  static/img/fa-brands-400.1d5619cd.svg (730 KiB)
  static/img/fa-solid-900.37bc7099.svg (897 KiB)
  static/img/fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d.svg (434 KiB)
  static/js/chunk-20bce5cc.30df4307.js (995 KiB)
  static/js/chunk-57fa210c.c3888579.js (1.07 MiB)
  static/js/chunk-a65568da.4fdf6ed9.js (338 KiB)
  static/js/chunk-elementUI.4a643ef0.js (698 KiB)
  static/js/chunk-libs.00525053.js (2.83 MiB)

 warning  

entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  app (4.15 MiB)
      static/css/chunk-elementUI.68c70ad5.css
      static/js/chunk-elementUI.4a643ef0.js
      static/css/chunk-libs.8f8abf3a.css
      static/js/chunk-libs.00525053.js
      static/css/app.d7f6f6a5.css
      static/js/app.c079bf5b.js


  File                                            Size                                                        Gzipped

  dist/static/js/chunk-libs.00525053.js           2898.95 KiB                                                 1040.47 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-57fa210c.c3888579.js       1091.28 KiB                                                 457.60 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-20bce5cc.30df4307.js       994.52 KiB                                                  211.99 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-elementUI.4a643ef0.js      697.86 KiB                                                  170.93 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-a65568da.4fdf6ed9.js       337.52 KiB                                                  86.54 KiB
  dist/static/js/app.c079bf5b.js                  211.37 KiB                                                  62.93 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-31981e0b.7613ba04.js       193.49 KiB                                                  65.62 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-60d45dd8.839e76cd.js       61.93 KiB                                                   14.38 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-3414ce86.37c45259.js       31.89 KiB                                                   5.23 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-b5efe21a.a3395984.js       7.96 KiB                                                    5.78 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-2d229048.78f49061.js       5.97 KiB                                                    1.79 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-6a52c0e3.a3d9d20a.js       3.24 KiB                                                    1.30 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-2d0d05e9.65c51df1.js       2.73 KiB                                                    1.15 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-be8bf048.fd1f66f4.js       2.05 KiB                                                    0.77 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-c17e5704.f75ec1f8.js       1.59 KiB                                                    0.86 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-4dd1ff3c.ee95460a.js       0.93 KiB                                                    0.53 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-595d9256.91c103e6.js       0.90 KiB                                                    0.49 KiB
  dist/static/js/chunk-2d0f0fdf.cb0ff0f4.js       0.47 KiB                                                    0.34 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-elementUI.68c70ad5.css    227.82 KiB                                                  34.54 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-libs.8f8abf3a.css         184.58 KiB                                                  37.35 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-595d9256.8fe9727b.css     32.46 KiB                                                   5.97 KiB
  dist/static/css/app.d7f6f6a5.css                27.21 KiB                                                   5.77 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-a65568da.8c917c68.css     16.77 KiB                                                   4.25 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-31981e0b.86a967f6.css     15.52 KiB                                                   4.04 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-57fa210c.bda1da5f.css     5.95 KiB                                                    1.36 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-b5efe21a.664d5134.css     4.65 KiB                                                    0.83 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-60d45dd8.c1d37798.css     4.08 KiB                                                    1.35 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-3414ce86.5b57b7c1.css     1.91 KiB                                                    0.70 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-c17e5704.e29807c0.css     0.71 KiB                                                    0.28 KiB
  dist/static/css/chunk-6a52c0e3.1f0ed01a.css     0.05 KiB                                                    0.07 KiB

  Images and other types of assets omitted.
```

I've tried by cloning fresh repo too. But sometimes it has expected result and most of the time it has unexpected output.

**DIFFERENCES**

- Built size is different (**Output-2:** 4.15 MiB) & (**Output-1:** 6.82 MiB)
- Number of Chunks are different (**Output-2:** 12-CSS, 18-JS) & (**Output-1:** 3-CSS, 3-JS)

Comment: whats the question

Comment: @Ifaruki I want Output-2. I want to know, why there is different output for the same code.

Comment: What do you mean by `same code`? Running `npm run build` 2 times in a row with the same `vue.config.js` is producing vastly different results?